# [eslint][node.js] eslint-disable not working

Tags: node.js, eslint

I'm trying to disable eslint for a line of code but to no effect.

I tried to tackle the problem as in [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules). One approach, used in C:...somepath...\index.js:

```
/* eslint-disable */
const fetch = (url, init) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(url, init));
/* eslint-enable */
```

And another approach, used in C:\Users...somepath...\shared\index.js:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
const fetch = (url, init) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(url, init));
```

None of them seem to work as while running `npx eslint "**/*.js"` I keep on getting:

```
C:\...somepath...\index.js
  6:32  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token import

C:\Users\...somepath...\shared\index.js
  11:7  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token import
```

I'm using commonjs, and yes, I know that import is not designed to be used out of es modules but according to [node-fetch documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) I can do so and the solution is working fine. Yet, eslint is still throwing errors. After failing to add some rules ignoring importing, I decided to just disable the problematic pieces of code.

I'm extending airbnb and my .eslintrc is as simple as that:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb"
}
```

Relevant dependencies/devDependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "node": "^16.17.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.10",
    "npm": "^8.19.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.2",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.7.1"
}
```

I've tried applying `/* eslint-disable */` to a whole file to check whether it works at all - no it doesn't. This led me to think whether airbnb doesn't have sth like `"noInlineConfig": true` set but I checked and it seems like not the case.

Can you please help me with the issue?

Comment: You can't disable parsing errors, because ESlint simply can't understand your file.

Comment: @AKX Oh okay, thank you for the explanation! So my whole approach is wrong from the beginning and after all I'm forced to use the old node-fetch with require.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) in your code, you need to set the language version to 2020 or higher. The preferred way to do so is to set a predefined [environment](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments) in your .eslintrc file:

```json
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "es2020": true
  }
}
```

to set the language version for a particular file only, use an override:

```json
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "overrides": [{
    "files": "./path/to/file.js",
    "env": {
      "es2020": true
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: I do not want to set es2020 for the whole project but rather make an exception for this one case of import or at least disable eslint there.

Comment: Thank you for the update although there are some buts to it. It still would not be perfect to set it to a whole file but I've decided to give it a go. It's not changing anything (tried firstly with override, then for all files just to check it). The file .eslintrc for sure works in general as, when I add different rules, the output of "npx eslint "**/index.js" " is correctly affected. However, changing env in general or by overriding seems to be omitted or not working.